# Grouping help needed

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a datebase where every step that a user takes in our system is measured.

I want to select ALL user ( column usuarioId ) where the last step on our plataform was :  "Resultado Idwall APROVADO" (mensagem column )

Here is an example of a user who went further than the step  "Resultado Idwall APROVADO"

[image: User Exaples]

I tried to use:

```
select *
from usuarioAnalise
where 1=1
and mensagem = 'Resultado Idwall APROVADO'
and criacaoData=max(criacaoData)
group by usuarioId
```

Since we have multiple logs for the same user, i though that i should take the user where the mensagem column is 'Resultado Idwall APROVADO' and this is the last log ( **criacaoData=max(criacaoData)** )

but it gives me the error line:
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: `and criacaoData = (select max(criacaoData) ...`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.

If you want all users whose last step is approvado, one option is to filter on the last record per group with `row_number()`, and then check if it has the expected status:

```
select ua.*
from (
    select ua.*,
        row_number() over(partition by usuarioId order by criacaoData desc) rn
    from usuarioAnalise ua
) ua
 where rn = 1 and mensagem = 'Resultado Idwall APROVADO'
```

On the other hand, if you want *all rows* of user whose last action is "Approvado, then you can use window function `first_value()`:

```
select *
from (
    select ua.*,
        first_value(mensagem) over(partition by usuarioId order by criacaoData desc) first_mensagem
    from usuarioAnalise ua
) ua
where first_mensagem = 'Resultado Idwall APROVADO'
```

Comment: This throws me "Incorret Sintax near row_number()

Comment: @MatheusBarreto: which database are you running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Im using Azure Data Studio

Comment: @MatheusBarreto: ok, so probably SQL Server is your database. The query should work. I just fixed a typo in the first query (missing comma).

Comment: Yet, it throws me the error message: Invalid column name 'usuarioAnalise'. Here, usuarioAnalise is the name of the database